# What is the $$FormScript_0 field in Document Properties in LotusScript used for?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I've searched all over to find any information I can about this field.  I have some emails that are being generated by one of my applications that crash notes each time you attempt to open them.  If I compare the Document properties of one of these emails to a normal email, I find that there are many of these fields: $$$FormScript_0, $$$FormScript, $$FormScript_0, $$FormScript, etc.

Anyone know why these fields are generated and what purpose they serve?  Just trying to rule them out as a cause of the crashed Notes.

MJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe those items mean that the form is stored in the document. Some code on that form is crashing the client.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the problem was with the form being stored in the document and there being a problem with the form.  It all boiled down to the following Call:

    Call Maildoc.Send(True)
    'The parameter determines whether the form is attached or not.  I changed the parameter
    ' to the following and it fixed the problem.
 
    Call Maildoc.Send(False)


Thanks for the help,

MJ